# при включении атрибута получаю ошибку 'error: section attribute not allowed for 'Mcalc''

Tags: c

Почему выдает ошибку при подключении атрибута?
Вот такой код:

```
__attribute__((section(".DIO")))
typedef struct {
float data[32];
int   size;
}Mcalc;
Mcalc MCALC;
```

Получаю ошибку `error: section attribute not allowed for 'Mcalc'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот атрибут можно ставить для переменной. В определении типа нельзя.

```
typedef struct {
  float data[32];
  int   size;
}Mcalc;

Mcalc MCALC  __attribute__((section(".DIO"))) ;
```

asm :

```
    .file   "secti.c"
    .text
    .globl  MCALC
    .section    .DIO,"aw",@progbits
    .align 32
    .type   MCALC, @object
    .size   MCALC, 132
MCALC:
    .zero   132
    .ident  "GCC: (SUSE Linux) 7.5.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: Такой-же вопрос на английском : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57550358/how-structure-can-be-mapped-with-section-attribute-in-a-c-program